# How to get rid of !M in SVN?

Tags: macos, svn

When I run `svn status` in Terminal, I get a *!M* in front of *screenshot0@2x.jpg* because I had renamed it to *introContent0@2x.jpg*.

```
A       iPhone/Resources/image/introContent0@2x.jpg
!M      iPhone/Resources/image/screenshot0@2x.jpg
```

I tried to `svn rm` and `svn revert` the *!M* file, but it this error is printed:

```
screenshot0@2x.jpg is scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rename a file in an SVN repository, you must use [svn move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) so that SVN keeps track of the change. If you rename it from your standard tools (e.g. from the Finder, or using the `mv` command) then SVN sees a new file, and it thinks the original file is missing.

In your situation, you should be able to delete your missing file with `svn remove iPhone/Resources/image/screenshot0@2x.jpg`. See [svn remove](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html).

Comment: I actually had to do `svn remove iPhone/Resources/image/screenshot0@2x.jpg@` (notice the @ at the end) because the @ was screwing up the parser